# Using array as list of allowed keys in type

Tags: typescript

I want to make this:

```
myArray = [50,100,300,500];

type MyType = {
[myArray]: {name:string,value:string}
};
```

so the object could have the values of the array as key.

I know I could use an enum to do that but I was wondering if I could use an array in any way.

The best scenario would be to use the array as type parameter but I also don't think it's possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were on a good path, the core feature required here are [Mapped Types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html).

`as const` ensured the array type is inferred to  `[50, 100, 300, 500]` instead of `number[]`.

```
const myArray = [50, 100, 300, 500] as const;

type arrayValues = (typeof myArray)[number];

type MyType = {
    [K in arrayValues]?: { name: string, value: string }
};

const foo: MyType = {
    "100": { name: 'foo', value: 'bar' }, // OK
    "150": { name: 'foo', value: 'bar' }, // KO
}
```

`?` Makes the key optionals. Without it, your object would be required to have all the keys of your array.

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAtgTwIICcUEMEwLwwNoCsADADQwCMRpMAzFWcUQLozoQyiRQDcAUAPT8YwmAD0A-L15QEABwCmrNJgBq6ADYBXee1wAKGQpAAzeMmUIAlHjCa4AI3komfQSIlTDigLIIAKnKKuADe+ADSMACWYEoYCGpaOkziAFwwoWDocPJp0CjRAOZkAG4a2rlQ+WAFMAC+da5Cwh68nNAwxiAgab4BCjjpvCIwAESURCNpGVk5MADknSBzJWWzc-boKHN1ZG4A8mFDImPEk+kwmdlpC13LMKWJ1xtbOzBuYXu8tUA)

Comment: When i look to your solution and Behemoth's one, both are easy to read and does what I want but is there a "better" way (or maybe a more recent way) ? Yours is maybe more flexible because I can potentialy add some additionnal key:value to MyType.

Answer (score 1):

It can be done with a [`const`-assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-4.html#const-assertions) and a `Partial` `Record`.

```
const myArray = [50, 100, 300, 500] as const;

type MyType = Partial<
  Record<(typeof myArray)[number], { name: string; value: string }>
>;
```

[TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAtgTwIICcUEMEwLwwNoCsADADQwCMRpMAzFWcUQLozoQyiRQDcAUL1AQAHAKYwAsggAqwsbgAK6FFACW6ADYAeAEojQKACaaAFINEgAZvGRpMASjxgArnABGIlEzIBvGGHRwIgBcMNAoKmAA5twwAG4aTsGhUOFRMAC%20AHyZfAD0uTCFAHoA-LxAA)